# Libc SIGSEGV when calling native method from java

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, native-methods

I'm trying to get my java implementation of the Amazon In-app Purchases SDK's PurchasingObserver to communicate back to my C++ code through a native method.

PurchasingObserver.java //excerpt

```
public class PurchasingObserver
{
    //...

    private native void postEvent(int type, String jsonData);
    // called by each of the four event handler methods, data is non-null
    // also tried it as native synchronized
}
```

AmazonInAppPurchaseHandler.cpp //excerpt

```
static AmazonInAppPurchaseHandler* AmazonInAppPurchaseHandler::s_pInstance(0); // dumbleton

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL  _NativePurchasingObserverPostEvent(JNIEnv* pEnv, jobject obj, jint type, jstring jsonData)
// friend function
{
  assert(type >= 0);
  assert(type < AmazonInAppPurchaseHandler::kNumEventTypes); // event type is in range
  assert(pEnv != 0); // JNI environment is valid

  printf("Stuff from the native callback: %d, %p\n", type, jsonData); // never gets printed.

  int jsonDataLen(0);
  const char* pJsonDataUtfChars(0);
  if(jsonData != 0)
  {
    jsonDataLen = pEnv->GetStringUTFLength(jsonData);
    pJsonDataUtfChars = pEnv->GetStringUTFChars(jsonData, 0);
  }

  assert(s_pInstance != 0); // got AmazonInAppPurchaseHandler instance
  s_pInstance->DoCallback(type, jsonDataLen, pJsonDataUtfChars);

  pEnv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jsonData, pJsonDataUtfChars);
}

static const JNINativeMethod karNativeMethod[] =
{
  { 
    "postEvent",
    "(ILjava/lang/String;)V",
    (void*)&_NativePurchasingObserverPostEvent
  }
};


AmazonInAppPurchaseHandler::AmazonInAppPurchaseHandler()
{
  assert(s_pInstance == 0); // is only instance
  s_pInstance = this;

  JNIEnv* pEnv(GetJNIEnv());
  assert(pEnv != 0); // got JNI environment

  jint  result(pEnv->RegisterNatives(cPurchaseObserver, karNativeMethod, 1));
  assert(AmazonInAppPurchaseHandler, result == 0); // successfully registered
}

AmazonInAppPurchaseHandler::~AmazonInAppPurchaseHandler()
{
  s_pInstance = 0;
}
```

As soon as I do anything that generates an event, the following happens:
1, event handler is called correctly, it does its logging.
2, it also logs "Posting event...", the last thing before calling postEvent().
3, the program crashes in libc with a SIGSEGV. (It refers to my application but note that the reverse dotcom name is truncated. I'm not sure if this is unusual.)
4, the tracing in the C++ _NativePurchasingObserverPostEvent is never reached.

Log:

> 12-05 10:24:47.380:
>   D/com.mycompany.amazoninapp.PurchasingObserver@41970368(4604):
>   onGetUserIdResponse:
>   (com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.GetUserIdResponse@4196cf98, requestId:
>   "dcf8e712-078b-4d47-9533-ee9ae544f53d", getUserIdRequestStatus:
>   "SUCCESSFUL", userId: "DefaultTestUser")
>
> 12-05 10:24:47.380:
>   D/com.mycompany.amazoninapp.PurchasingObserver@41970368(4604):
>   Posting event...
>
> 12-05 10:24:47.380: A/libc(4604): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at
>   0x00000008 (code=1), thread 4604 (y.amazoninapp)
>
> 12-05 10:24:47.390: I/AmazonSDKTester(3529): Sending Purchase Updates
>   Response Broadcast
>   ({"revokedSkus":[],"offset":"1354703087397","status":"SUCCESSFUL","requestId":"b9aee42e-4f50-42c4-8a12-ba9eb1d19155","isMore":false,"receipts":[{"sku":"com.mycompany.amazoninapp.ENTI01","token":"eyJ0eXBlIjoiTk9OQ09OU1VNQUJMRSIsInNrdSI6ImNvbS5wbGF5ZXJ0aHJlZS5hbWF6b25pbmFw\ncC5FTlRJMDEifQ\n","itemType":"ENTITLED"}],"userId":"DefaultTestUser"})

I went through the iterations of getting the JNI class name and method signature strings right (we're past UnsatisfiedLinkErrors); I'm double-checking against null Strings. The rest of my JNI works fine, the Amazon In-app Purchasing UI is displayed correctly. Events are guaranteed to be not generated prior to registering the native method.

What is causing the crash?

Thank you for your input in advance.

Comment: Start your program, then launch gdb and attach to the PID of your program.  That should help you isolate the context of your null pointer access.

Comment: Does the AmazonInAppPurchaseHandler constructor even get called? Where are you creating the object?

Comment: I've just run into the same problem. Do you remember what fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your function as using the `C` calling convention. Declare it as `extern "C"` as in:

```
extern "C" void _NativePurchasingObserverPostEvent(JNIEnv* pEnv, jobject obj, jint type, jstring jsonData)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; I've followed it, then cleanbuilt and redeployed the app, but I'm afraid the crash is still happening, yielding the exact same error message. (I've also tried adding the JNIEXPORT void JNICALL to the declaration, to no avail.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `javah` to create a header that you `#include` into your C++ code, instead of writing the function prototype yourself.